# How to get the caption of a text object in Python?

Tags: python, text-object

I've got a Blender file with a lot of text objects and I want to do some scripting modifications on specific text with specific caption.

Is it possible to get the caption of a text curve in Blender?

For example, in the image below the caption that I want to find in Python is: 'This is a test'
[image]

Comment: Text mesh? If it is a text curve you can get it's content via `text_curve.body`. You can get the text curve either from `text_curve=bpy.data.curves[text_curve_name]` or from an object using it `text_curve=obj.data`.

Comment: Mmmh yep I've used the wrong term. Of course I use a text curve :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can access the text via the [body](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.types.TextCurve.html#bpy.types.TextCurve.body) attribute,

Example:

```
# assume active object
obj = context.object
curve_text = obj.data

print(curve_text.body)

# set a new string
curve_text.body = "This is a NEW test :)"
```